# Django Forms - How to change an attribute from a field?

Tags: django, html, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

The Django forms functionality generates the html code for my form fields.

I would like to change some attributes or add some for a specific field from that form.

For example I would like to specify a class for a field.

How can I do that?

I read an answer on SO that I could do it like this:

```
city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'anyclass'}))
```

but i get an error, that attrs does not exist or is undefined...

**UPDATE**

Here is my forms.py

from django import forms
from HelloUprise.models import Goal
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class GoalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    deadline = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))


class Meta:
    model=Goal
    fields = ['goal', 'description', 'deadline', 'priority']
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError at /
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

**Traceback** Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in resolve
            for pattern in self.url_patterns: ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module
            self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module
        **import**(name) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Barosan\Documents\GitHub\uprisedev\UpriseApplication\UpriseApplication\urls.py in 
    url(r'^', include('HelloUprise.urls')), ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls__init__.py in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module
        **import**(name) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Barosan\Documents\GitHub\uprisedev\UpriseApplication\HelloUprise\urls.py in 
from HelloUprise import views ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Barosan\Documents\GitHub\uprisedev\UpriseApplication\HelloUprise\views.py in 
from HelloUprise.forms import GoalForm ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Barosan\Documents\GitHub\uprisedev\UpriseApplication\HelloUprise\forms.py in 
class GoalForm(forms.ModelForm): ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Barosan\Documents\GitHub\uprisedev\UpriseApplication\HelloUprise\forms.py in GoalForm
    deadline = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py in **init**
        super(BaseTemporalField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars

Comment: That is exactly how you do it, and you wouldn't get that error from that code. You should post the exact code and the full traceback.

Comment: Here it is...if i can provide anymore information please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done what you showed in the example. Instead of using a widget, you're trying to pass another instance of the field. That doesn't work, as the error shows.

It should be:

```
deadline = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

note the use of `DateInput` instead of `DateField`.